# Vite incorrectly resolving files in public folder (Vue project)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

[image]

Folder structure is like this above.

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

export default defineConfig({
plugins: [vue()],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
},
})
```

When I try to run dev server it gives me this error
[image]

under the /public/preview folder i have some sub folders that hold it's own index.html and .js files inside the assets. It's odd having this error because I don't event imported any of these into my main app.

What might cause this to happen? Might be looking for those .js files in /src/assets instead of it's own root/assets ?

All of html files from /public/preview looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user- 
scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<title>Test</title>

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" href="icons/favicon.png">

<style>
</style>
<!-- built styles file will be auto injected -->
<script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/index.4277377f.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/index.4ceaebd1.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>


 </body>

 </html>
```

**EDIT: Okay I found a solution by changing the href path, adding "./" to start of the path.

this -> src="./assets/index.4277377f.js" instead of -> src="assets/index.4277377f.js"**

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a solution by changing the href path, adding `./` to start of the path.

Use `src="./assets/index.4277377f.js"` instead of `src="assets/index.4277377f.js"`.